# Ruby on Rails DataTables - this CSS is screwing up my paginate buttons. How do I get rid of it?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

Ever since DataTables were updated when I ran "bundle" today, my paginate buttons got screwed up again. For example, when I hover the button, there's a big black border that surrounds each button and it's extremely unattractive. I've narrowed it down to this:

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button:hover {
  color: white !important;
  border: 1px solid #111111;
  background-color: #585858;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #585858), color-stop(100%, #111111));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #585858 0%, #111111 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #585858 0%, #111111 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #585858 0%, #111111 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #585858 0%, #111111 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #585858 0%, #111111 100%);
  /* W3C */
}
```

Other than deleting this from the original CSS (because it'll come back when there's another update I'm sure), how can I override this to where NONE of this takes effect? Just simply removing this temporarily worked for me, but I need a more permanent solution.